# Card layout - Active Item - sencha touch

Tags: layout, extjs4, sencha-touch

I am having one view which is in card layout.
Card is having 2 sub views.

Now I want to get the activeitem.
In extjs I am using this code:

```
 activeItem = layout.getActiveItem().itemId;
```

but in sencha touch , for card layout , there is no such method named getActiveItem() for card layout.
I have referred sencha touch docs and I found that.

Anybody knows the alternative for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
layout: 'card',
items: [
    {
        html: "First Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Second Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Third Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Fourth Item"
    }
]
});

panel.setActiveItem(1);
```

It also have getActiveItem() method to work with.

Refer http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card

Comment: panel.layout.setActiveItem(2);